# Hyperref with hyperfootnotes is broken

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

in my PDF I can click on footnotes, but the link doesn't lead to the footnote entry at the bottom of the page. I also use the footnotebackref package which works fine.
Any suggestions what is wrong?
Here is the code snippet:

```
    \usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
             unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
            xetex]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{footnotebackref}
 %\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\else
 \usepackage[unicode=false]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{footnotebackref}
 %\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={$author-meta$},
            pdftitle={$title-meta$},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=$if(citecolor)$$citecolor$$else$blue$endif$,
            urlcolor=$if(urlcolor)$$urlcolor$$else$[RGB]{41,86,150}$endif$,
            linkcolor=$if(linkcolor)$$linkcolor$$else$grey1$endif$,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same} % don't use monospace font for urls
```

Comment: The variables and `if` blocks in `\hypersetup` look like Pandoc, is that involved in some way? Also it would help if you make a complete document, that can actually be compiled and has one or two footnotes in it. This makes it easier for potential answerers to try to reproduce to problem and try out possible solutions.

Comment: footnote and links are complicated, you can't debug problems from a snippet. Always provide a small but complete example.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but it was a mistake of mine and it is solve. And yes  I use pandoc and thanks for the hint to provide complete examples.